# Space in my block element in dropdown navbar

Tags: html, css, navigation, dropdown, nav

In my dropdown nav when you hover over an object there is an amount of space I can't figure out how to remove. To be more clear its this:
[Image of navbar dropdown with the space im talking about circled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5BBz.png)

You can view the navbar on my github website: https://cyrusmusic101.github.io/fca-website-2021.github.io/

Code to website: https://github.com/CyrusMusic101/fca-website-2021.github.io

Answer (score 1):

```
.headertop ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    line-height: 70px; < ----------------- here is the issue
    left: -10px;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: okay how would I go about fixing this? Thats how I am keeping my nav items centered.

Comment: Just lower it from 70px to 30px or whatever until you get the desired result.

Comment: Okay thank you this is how I keep my text centered on my navbar. How do I go about fixing this? Keeping it centered that is where it is.

Comment: Line height sets how high the line of text is not how's it's centered. Changing it won't affect the centre alignment. See the reference here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp